# How to transform a XML Schema Design (XSD) with XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xsd

What is a good approach to handle different namespaces when transforming XSD files with import statements?

Is there an example of XSLT (1.0 or 2.0) Stylesheet that transforms XSD files with include multiple imports and namespaces?

Comment: This question is too general. Please, provide an example schema and define how the result should be produced from it.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://blog.springframework.com/arjen/archives/2006/07/27/xslt-that-transforms-from-xsd-to-wsdl/) is a general stylesheet that transforms a XSD to a WSDL that might be of help. Of course you will need to supply parameters to it so it knows what is a message etc.

Also see the The [Schema Lightener / Schema Flattener / WSDL Flattener tool](http://www.xmlhelpline.com/tools/)